# Finding 3 columns with highest value in each row and put their name in a new data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have the following data frame:

```
temp1=data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),p1=c(0,0,1,1,2),p2=c(9,2,3,5,3),p3=c(1,4,10,3,7),p4=c(4,4,7,1,10))

  id p1 p2 p3 p4
  1  0  9  1  4
  2  0  2  3  4
  3  1  3 10  7
  4  1  5  3  1
  5  2  3  7 10
```

for each id  I want to extract top three columns with highest value and put them in a new data frame something like this:

```
id top1 top2 top3
 1  p2   p4   p3
 2  p4   p3   p2
 3  p3   p4   p2
 4  p2   p3   p4/p1
 5  p4   p3   p2
```

in case there are two identical value we are allowed to put them in arbitrary order.

Comment: @akrun i would appreciate your help

Comment: Is there only one row corresponding to one id or same id can be in multiple rows?

Comment: there is only one row corresponding to one id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library("tidyr") 
library("dplyr")
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),p1=c(0,0,1,1,2),p2=c(9,2,3,5,3),p3=c(1,4,10,3,7),p4=c(4,4,7,1,10))
df2 <- gather(df,col,val,-id)   
res <- group_by(df2,id) %>% arrange(id,desc(val)) %>% summarise(top1 = first(col),top2 = nth(col,2),top3 = nth(col,3))
```

Results in

```
#      id  top1  top2  top3
#    <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#  1     1    p2    p4    p3
#  2     2    p3    p4    p2
#  3     3    p3    p4    p2
#  4     4    p2    p3    p1
#  5     5    p4    p3    p2
```

following new information

```
res <- group_by(df2,id) %>% mutate(r=rank(-(val/sum(val)*100),ties.method = "min")) %>% arrange(id,r) %>% summarise(top1 = first(col),top2 = nth(col,2),top3 = nth(col,3))
```

results in

```
#        id  top1  top2  top3
#      <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#    1     1    p2    p4    p3
#    2     2    p3    p4    p2
#    3     3    p3    p4    p2
#    4     4    p2    p3    p1
#    5     5    p4    p3    p2
```

Comment: It's quite handy, an alternate to `tidyR` is `reshape2`

Comment: can we modify the code to fill the columns top1:top3 by the ratio? for example for id1,the top1 column would be 4/14 *100

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `apply` with `rank` from `base R`

```
 m1 <- t(apply(temp1[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) {
               i1 <- rank(-x, ties.method = "min")
                i2 <- i1[i1 %in% 1:3]
                tapply(names(i2), i2, FUN=paste, collapse="/")} ))
d1 <- setNames(cbind(temp1[1], m1), c("id", paste0("top", 1:ncol(m1))))
d1
#  id top1 top2  top3
#1  1   p2   p4    p3
#2  2   p4   p3    p2
#3  3   p3   p4    p2
#4  4   p2   p3 p1/p4
#5  5   p4   p3    p2
```

---

If we need to get the proportions in place of the column names

```
d2 <- d1
lst <- apply(temp1[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) {
           i1 <- rank(-x, ties.method = "min")
            i2 <- i1[i1 %in% 1:3]
            tapply(names(i2), i2, FUN= list)} )

lst1 <- setNames(lapply(lst, function(x) unlist(x)), seq_len(nrow(temp1)))

d2[-1] <- t(sapply(
           relist(unlist(lapply(seq_along(lst1), function(i) {
           x <- temp1[i, lst1[[i]]]
    x/sum(x)
          })), 
     skeleton = lst), 
     function(x) sapply(x, function(y) toString(round(y,2)))))
d2 
#   id top1 top2     top3
# 1  1 0.64 0.29     0.07
# 2  2 0.44 0.33     0.22
# 3  3  0.5 0.35     0.15 
# 4  4  0.5  0.3 0.1, 0.1
# 5  5  0.5 0.35     0.15
```

Comment: can we modify the code to fill the columns top1:top3 by the ratio? for example for id1,the top1 column would be 4/14 *100

Comment: @sanaz Is it based on the ratio.  In that case `rank(-((x/sum(x))*100), ties.method = "min")` changes in the code .  why is `9/14` not the top column?

Comment: @sanaz Why is 9/14 not the top column?

Comment: Yes my mistake it should be 9/14, but is there a way to use tidyr to do this?

Comment: @sanaz You already have a solution with `tidyr`, but I think the `apply` based solution should be faster as we are not `melt`ing

Comment: actually i don't want to change the column names , just want to fill top1 column with 9/14

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116461/discussion-between-sanaz-and-akrun).

Comment: @sanaz I updated the post.  Please check if that is what you wanted